# Iframe video not occupying full width

Tags: reactjs, iframe

I am new to React JS and also new to any component based framework. For learning purpose I am creating video tutorial like website.

I am using `iframe` element to render the video and giving it 100% width to occupy full width. The problem us `iframe` element generating its own `html` with `video` element as child of `body`.

[image]

Now to make video occupy full width I have to apply `width: 100%` on `video` element which I have tested from browser developer tool. In my JSX there is only `iframe` and no `video` element so I am applying style like this

```
iframe: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '80vh',
    "& video": {
    width: "100% !important"
    }
},

return (
        <div>
            {
                 <Iframe url={this.props.current_chapter.chapter_video}
                         className={classes.iframe}/>
            }
        </div>
);
```

So I have two questions

1. why `iframe` rendering its own html ?
2. How can I make `video` occupy full width?

Answer (score 0):

1. An iframe is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.
2. When you give `width:100%` for an element; it always takes; its parent full width. So first you should give proper width to its parent.

   ```
   .container: {
      width: '400px'
    } 

   return (
       <div class="container">
         <Iframe url={this.props.current_chapter.chapter_video} lassName={classes.iframe}/>
       </div>    
   );
   ```